# How to make UITableviewCell (custom) height is depends on the contents?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

In my UIViewController I have a UITableView with custom cell.

Please check below image for screenshot.
[image]

In that I am giving "multi line " feature to UILabel (The selected label in screenshot) but I have 2 problems now.

When I open this viewcontroller I can see lots of blank space if my UILabel (Description label) have very small text. How can I manage these white spaces?

Please check the app screenshots
[image]

My code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";

    InfoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[InfoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    cell.header.text=[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.details.text=[details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.header sizeToFit];
    [cell.details sizeToFit];
    return cell;
}
```

Please help to clear these issues

1. How to make UILabel text size dynamic instead of fixed multiline?
2. How to make UITableViewCell dynamic depends on its contents height?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = @“Your text”;
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:YourFontSize];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(TextviewWidth, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSLog(@"labelSize : %f", labelSize.height);
    return labelSize.height;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @“CustomCell”;

    CommentCell *cell = (CommentCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSString *cellText = @“LabelText”;
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:yourFontSize];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(LabelWidth, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    cell.lbl.frame = CGRectMake(cell.lbl.frame.origin.x, cell.lbl.frame.origin.y, cell.lbl.frame.size.width, labelSize.height);
    cell.lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
}
```

Comment: may i know why you have sugested this solution

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *strYourText = @"Testing Case ";
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *objPS = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    objPS.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;//here you have to pass the Line break mode which you have to label
    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 1000.0);///width: label width and set the height 1000.0
    CGSize textSizeForLabel = [strYourText boundingRectWithSize:labelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : objPS,NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]} context:nil].size;
    float labelHeight =ceilf(textSizeForLabel.height);//this are the only lable height.if there are other UIControls then add their heights and retuns.
    //Like if One More Buttons is there in cell then return the button height with dynamic lable height (e.g. return labelHeight+buttonHeight );
//herer we are consider there is a only one label is there so return label height
    return labelHeight;




}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";

    InfoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[InfoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    cell.header.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.header.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    NSString *strYourText = @"Testing Case ";
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *objPS = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    objPS.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;//here you have to pass the Line break mode which you have to label
    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(cell.header.frame.size.width, 1000.0);///width label width and set the height 1000.0
    CGSize textSizeForLabel = [strYourText boundingRectWithSize:labelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : objPS,NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]} context:nil].size;
    float labelHeight =ceilf(textSizeForLabel.height);
    [cell.header setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.header.frame.origin.x, cell.header.frame.origin.x, cell.header.frame.origin.x, labelHeight)];
    cell.header.text=strYourText;


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: This is not working for me ..i have create a sample project please check this link.

Comment: I am giving you only one lable example.but in your uitableview cell there are more than one lable so you have to add static size for remaining label.